# implicit declaration of function even though i have included the file?

Tags: c, arduino, pwm

my project is almost working but i get 1

> > Warning:
> >     "implicit declaration of function 'init_phase_correct' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]"

have have the function called in my main

```
int main(void)
{
    volatile char start_flag=0;
  uart0_Init ( MYUBRRF );
  DDRB |=(1<<PB7);
  sei();  //enable global interrupt
  initAdc();      
  data = 'a';
  ADCSRA |=(1<<ADIE);
  init_phase_correct();
```

and init_phase_correct is included i the top in

```
#include "PWM.h"
```

that links to

```
/*
 * IncFile1.h
 *
 * Created: 23-04-2015 11:30:38
 *  Author: Martin Egsdal
 */ 


#ifndef INCFILE1_H_


#define INCFILE1_H_

extern void init_fastPWM();
extern void init_phase_correct();
extern void init_ph_frPWM();
extern void init_phase_correct_alt();


#endif /* INCFILE1_H_ */
```

and in the C file it is:

```
void init_phase_correct(){
TCCR0A|=(1<<COM0A1)|(1<<WGM00); //Clear OC0A on Compare Match when up-counting. Set OC0A on Compare Match when down-counting
TCCR0B =(1<<CS01);   //prescalling by 8 
OCR0A =102;  //40 duty cycle    
TCNT0= 0;
DDRB |= (1<<DDB7);// configure OC0A pin for output  
}
```

when i rightclick init_phase_correct() in my main i can see the 2 implentations - so why is it "Wimplicit-function-declaration"?

Comment: What is the name of header, where `init_phase_correct()` is declared? The one `ifdef`ed with `INCFILE1_H_` ? Is it `PWM.h` or is it another file *included* by `PWM.h`?

Comment: @mch: tried- no diffrence

Comment: The inclusion guard `INCFILE1_H_` looks pretty generic. Haven't you used the same name to protect another header file? You could also try to run only the preprocessor (with `-E`) to check whether the file was actually included as intended.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek - good spotted - that was the error - was from some old code -.- thanks! :)

Comment: @Martin Yes, I thought so. My second sight works as usual :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see, that your header file, which contains declaration of `init_phase_correct()` is wrapped with include guard with some auto-generated name (`INCFILE1_H_`).

Also, you did not specify, whether `init_phase_correct()` is declared inside `PWM.h` or maybe another file, that is *included by* `PWM.h`.

Without more code, I cannot say for sure, but my clairvoyance skill tells me, that `INCFILE1_H_` may be used as include guard in another file - either `PWM.h` itself or another, that is being included *before* file, that contains declaration of `init_phase_correct()`.